# Excel - get the row and column of the result of an array function

Tags: arrays, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet, where the first column contains the name of a supplier and the second column contains the price from that supplier. Some of the prices are blank. I have an array formula at the bottom of the price column

```
{=min(if(b1:b35<>0;b1:b35))}
```

which gives me the minimum price, skipping blanks and zeros. This works fine.

Now I want a cell to contain the name of the supplier with the minimum price. I think I can do this using the INDIRECT function. The column will be 1, because that is my supplier column, but how do I figure out which row had the result found by the above formula?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: `=INDEX(A1:A35,MATCH(min(if(b1:b35<>0;b1:b35)),B1:B35,0))`

Comment: I am actually using Openoffice Calc version 4.1.11 saving as Excel 2000/XP. The above formula gives me and Err:508. I think the problem might be the commas, which should be semicolons.  When I change those, I get #VALUE! as a result.

Comment: Did you array enter like you did the other formula?  And the use of `;` vs `,` is a local thing.  For me it is `,`